# Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session does not work in ZF 2.1.1

Tags: zend-framework2

i update ZF from 2.0.6 to 2.1.1, Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session does not work. 
this is my project code, 2 project in 2 vesion, 2.0.6 work, but 2.1.1 hasn't

thanks for help

Comment: Seem to recall having to explicitly tell the Container to use my session manager when I switched to 2.1 Maybe try adding `\Zend\Session\Container::setDefaultManager($yourSessionManagerInstance);` to wherever you're composing your SessionManager instance

Comment: Please post your code here, don't make us download code from some dodgy looking site.

Comment: i don't know makus
@Crisp: thanks for help, i'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have restarted your browser after updating. Perhaps it sounds silly, but it is something that is easy to forget. I ran into a problem until doing so myself and have heard of several others encountering problems. Also, check the changelog for the past few updates; I believe it was in 2.0.7 (possibly) that there was an update that would break session management in some situation. I cannot seem to find a reference anymore, but if I remember correctly, it was related to using properties directly on the storage object, e.g. like below.

`$storage->something = 'some_value';`

If I remember correctly, this is no longer possible and you should use `offsetGet` and `offsetSet` instead if you are using the `Storage` class directly like that. If you are doing like this, it is worth researching this a bit and trying to see if you still get the error with the other approach. Alternatively, you can use the `Zend\Session\Container` class like below ([or more detailed](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2)).

```
$user_session = new \Zend\Session\Container('user');

$user_session->username = 'Andy0708'; // Write to session
$username = $user_session->username; // Read from session
```

You really have to provide more information in your question so that people can answer it properly. Until then, we can only really guess.